# Could not run adb reverse: spawnSync Typo in file location?

Tags: android, react-native, adb

I'm following a tutorial on React-Native but when I try to connect to the emulator in the command prompt a message pops up on the emulator from google securities asking if they can monitor risks, but nothing else happens

In the log I get the error Could not run adb reverse, but the file location is off as well (I think) should |AppData not be \AppData?

Here's the complete log:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 3s
27 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 26 up-to-date
Running C:\Users\Rebecca|AppData\Local\Android|sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulato
r-5554 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
Could not run adb reverse: spawnSync C:\Users\Rebecca|AppData\Local\Android|sdk/
platform-tools/adb ENOENT
Starting the app on emulator-5554 (C:\Users\Rebecca|AppData\Local\Android|sdk/pl
atform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell am start -n com.albums/com.albums.MainAc
tivity)...

D:\Projects\ReactNative\albums>adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device
```

Comment: This question should not be marked as a duplicate to the linked one, because in this question the terminal gives 'BUILD SUCCESSFUL', but in the linked one marked as a duplicate, the terminal gives 'BUILD FAILED', a rather big difference IMHO.